# Belt drive, rear sprocket can move sideways

Tags: belt-drive

I have (RieseMüller/Bosch/Nuvinci/center track) and the rear sprocket can move slightly sideways.

Is this on purpose or is there anything loose?

Comment: It could be by design, on the theory that the sprocket will naturally self-center to an optimal position.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ben from Gates Technical Support here, go ahead and drop us a line with any questions at carbondrive@gates.com. There could be a few things going on here but that sprocket should not have any side to side play. More than likely, a snap ring is missing or there may be some wear on either the sprocket or hub driver. Shoot us an email and we will get into the detail!

Comment: Done. Talked to your colleagues (you?) with great result. I found a bicycle shop with the right stuff on my way home and decided to let them have a look (instead of me). My cycle will spend the night there, in the warmth of the shop.

Comment: Exactly what it was. The snap ring had gone missing (wasn't even on the hub any more(!)).

Answer (score 3):

I do not have a wide breadth of knowledge, but as far as I know, the sprocket itself should be fixed in place and not move on its own in any direction. From the pictures I found on the internet of a Riese Müller Nuvinci, the belt on that electric bike is also not designed to move sideways.

It could be that you've just got a simple tightening job to do here, but without being there in person, I don't think I'd have much more advice. Apart from "don't ride it until this is fixed". It would be a shame to have it start sheering either the front or rear sprocket or the belt itself.